# Skype Url not working in Objective C?skype://USER_NAME?call (New Skype Have Disabled the Feature)

Tags: ios, objective-c, skype, openurl

I am using open URL for the Skype application to call the specific user from my iOS App.
but following code just opens Skype but does not call the specified user name.

can anyone please guide me on why it's not calling.

```
- (IBAction)callSkypeUser:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"skype://USER_NAME?call"];
    NSLog(@"url = %@", urlString);

    BOOL result = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    NSLog(@"result = %d", result);
}
```

Comment: Check Skype docs, check if you're passing the right data via the URL scheme. There is hardly enough info here for anybody to do anything other than guess at what your problem might be.

Comment: what you mean by harldy enough info??? this is the only 4 line to make a call..its working in webpage but not in ios

Comment: @B Webpage? You mean you tried in in Safari? That, for instance, is very useful info that should be in the question because it shows that the URL is probably OK.

Answer (score 2):

Your URL is not valid.

According to [Skype reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745885%28v=office.15%29.aspx) your URL string should be like:

```
NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"skype:USER_NAME?call"];
```

Comment: @BhavikKama: Check whether the user name is correct. Try with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"skype:echo123?call"]];`

Comment: yes..i tried with that also..but its doing same..no error just opening the skype app

Comment: there is any possibilities that skype doesnt supports it anymore to calling the username?

Comment: @BhavikKama: No, their document is last updated on Jun 02, 2014. So think it'll support the URI.

Comment: so can you give me idea what to do next..?

Comment: @BhavikKama: let me check the issue, I'm creating a sample project for checking the issue

Comment: @BhavikKama: It is not working, I think they disabled it in the new build.

Comment: This is when practice and theory collide. :-)

Comment: Any updates on this, still doesn't work. As I think something went wrong in there app release.

Comment: I just received an email from Skype Development Program Manager saying  "I can confirm that there is a known issue with the Skype 5.x branch and the team plan to add Skype URIs back to this client in an upcoming release."